# How to make a nav stretch across the entire width in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have the following navbar code in React with JSX. I'm using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html) to style the navbar, and want it to stretch across the full length of the browser. I have tried `style={{width: '100%'}}`, but that doesn't work. How can I make the navbar stretch across the entire page?

```
<nav style={{width: '100%' /* this doesn't work */}}>
            <div className="nav-wrapper red darken-2 nav-extended">
          <Link
            to={/**/}
            className="left brand-logo"
          >
          Title
          </Link>
          <ul className="right">{/**/}</ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: If you would need to ignore any ancestors' widths, you can use `'100vw'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `100vw`, which stands for 100 viewport width. 100% will be the width of the containing parent, which may be less than the viewport's width.